# images that squishes when I add more using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, amcharts

I'm using amchart and I want to display multiple charts in one page (as columns), my problem is that I don't want scroll bar no matter how many charts I add (yes I want them to squish) also when I display only one chart I want it in it's normal size (not squished or small)

How can I achieve that?
I'm trying now with images and if it works I will do it on my charts.

html:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OUla6mK.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/M16WzMd.jpg"/>
    </div>
        <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/M16WzMd.jpg"/>
    </div>
        <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/M16WzMd.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{    overflow-y : hidden;}
.content {
    background-color: yellow;    

}

.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    flex-direction: column;

    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;  
    align-items: center;

    background-color: red;

}

.cell {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto; 

    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;

    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}
img {max-height:100%;}
```

on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89dtxt6s/356/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**: Add the following to `.row` to ensure it fills the viewport height:

```
.row {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

**Step 2**: You need to give each `.cell` a flex display. Additionally, you'll need to adjust your `flex-basis` (third argument to the shorthand) to 100%. Finally, you'll need to set `min-height` to zero, in order for each element to totally shrink, if need be.

```
.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 100%; /* no longer auto */
  min-height: 0;
}
```

**Step 3**: Add a one-hundred percent width and height to the image.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Result**: squishy images. Ugly? Sure. But I'm not judging.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/jaunkv7k/

Comment: Works in Mac Chrome but not Mac Firefox. For some reason, the flex basis doesn't work and the images are displayed in full size, and therefor overflow the .row container.

Comment: Yes same for me it works on Chrome but not Firefox or Explorer

Comment: Should be working now, @user8423460. Updated the fiddle as well.

Comment: @user8423460 I verified this works in Chrome, FF, IE11.

Comment: It does! Thank you so much I really appreciate it :)